# Recompensas para perguntas respondidas

Tags: debate, perguntas, recompensa

Minha duvida é a seguinte eu faço uma pergunta que por algum motivo não teve muita atenção então por consequência tenho poucas respostas mas uma delas funciona para mim, então marco a resposta como certa, entretanto as vezes não tem como saber se aquela é realmente a melhor solução.

Minha pergunta é:
**posso oferecer uma recompensa para uma pergunta já respondida ?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sim pode. As recompensas são para isso mesmo. Chamar a atênção a uma pergunta ou compensar uma boa resposta, mesmo depois de respondida.

Comment: Obrigado @Sergio :D